# Remove an LVM partition on top of windows partition

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, lvm

I wanted to install ubuntu in dual boot with windows 10, but I accidentally select the options: "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" + "Use LVM with the new Ubuntu Installation". When the warning popup window is arrived I immediately clicked on cancel but the LVM is still set up.

I can't boot on windows anymore. Is there a way to reset the LVM partition to recover the windows partition? And if no, is it possible to recover data on the former windows?

I put 3 captures: 2 for the list of partitions, and 1 for the options I selected when I wanted to install ubuntu.

[List of partitions (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaTyF.jpg)
[List of partitions (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38VVG.jpg)
[Selected Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2l1Xq.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your 500GB ubuntu lvm is taking up your 500GB sda2, with only 536MB of sda1 left, unless you have two drives it looks like you completely overwrote Windows...

Since it doesn't look like you used encryption (it often "zero-fills" everything) you might still be able to recover some files from Windows (probably using a [PhotoRec](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec)-like data carving program, or less likely with [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)) but I really doubt you can just recover the complete Windows install - now is a good time to recover from your backups.

Comment: IMO, there is a possibility to be recovered the entire partition table, but, I can't say nothing more, right now.. it was long time ago.